# Asp.Net and Angular trying to send an Array of Objects to a Post API

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm using the USDA food database to try to make an app that will tell you if you've gotten your daily recommendations of vitamins. I'm getting data just fine, but I'm wondering if it was possible to send that data from Angular to the C# api, so I can add the array of strings and int to a total count model.
How would I route this and what kind of data should I tell the API to expect?

The error I'm getting right now is:

> Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/apiFood[object Object]'."
>   MessageDetail: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'apiFood[object Object]'."

I've tried :

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]ValueVM toEat)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
```

just to see if it would route, but it didn't work out.

I'm sending the data with an ngclick="add(display)" which goes to this function in the controller:

```
$scope.add = function (display) {
    FoodFactory.add(display).then(function (data) {

   });
};
```

and this function in the factory:

```
o.add = function (display) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var config = { contentType: 'application/json' };
    $http.post('api/apiFood' + display, config).success(function (data) {
        defer.resolve(data);
    });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

Comment: If you are sending an array.Then use `[FromUri]List<ValueVM> toEat` instead of `[FromUri]ValueVM toEat`

Comment: Please show how you are sending data to the controller. This error clearly indicates that you are sending wrong object.

Comment: Please explain why you create a promise when `$http.post` returns a promise itself.

Comment: @Phill I didn't know that. I'll try it without a promise. I'm new to angular

Comment: @QuocDuong you can do: `return $http.post(...).then(function(result) { return result.data; });` which would remove all your need for your own promise and give you the same result.

Comment: @Phill sounds neat. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
public class toEat
{
public int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
}
```

In your ApiController

```
public class EatController : ApiController 
{
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<toEat> list)     
   {
        return Ok();
   }       
}
```

Your request

```
function Request() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: (your serialized array),
     async: false,
     success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
  });
}
```